# real time location track

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, google-location-services

In my app I am required to implement real time location tracking and find the total distance traveled by person. I have tried using the Google location manager api. I can successfully fetch the location from a device while traveling. But the distance between source and destination is wrong. It does not seem to be accurate. Here is the code for my background service that fetches location and calculates distance.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "gpstest";
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 5;
    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER),
    };
    Location mLastLocation;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private double lat;
    private double log;
    private RetrofitClient.APIServiceGetDistanceMap apiServiceGetDistanceMap;
    private RetrofitClient.MakeMyTrip makeMyTrip;
    private String id;
    private String t_id;
    private boolean isStop = false;
    private double srclat;
    private double srclog;
    private double destlat;
    private double destlog;
    private double total;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");

        lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
        log = intent.getDoubleExtra("log", 0);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLastLocation.setLatitude(0);
            mLastLocation.setLongitude(0);
        }

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(720000000);

        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "TAG");
        wifiLock.acquire();


        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("my", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = sharedPref.getString("user_name", null);
        id = String.valueOf(sharedPref.getInt("id", 0));
        t_id = sharedPref.getString("t_id", "");

        initializeLocationManager();
        apiServiceGetDistanceMap = RetrofitClient.getDistanceMap(Constants.MAP_URL);
        makeMyTrip = RetrofitClient.makeTrip(Constants.BASE_URL);
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();


        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }


        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > LOCATION_INTERVAL;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -LOCATION_INTERVAL;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 10;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether two providers are the same
     */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {


        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
//            mLastLocation.setLatitude(lat);
//            mLastLocation.setLongitude(log);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);

            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                String source = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()).concat(",").concat(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));


                String destination = String.valueOf(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())).concat(",").concat(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                apiServiceGetDistanceMap.getMapDate(source, destination, "driving").enqueue(new Callback<MapData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<MapData> call, Response<MapData> response) {
                        ArrayList<Row> rowArrayList = new ArrayList<Row>();
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            rowArrayList = (ArrayList<Row>) response.body().getRows();
                            double distance = 0;


                            if (rowArrayList.size() > 0) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < rowArrayList.size(); i++) {


                                    for (int j = 0; j < rowArrayList.get(i).getElements().size(); j++) {

                                        if (rowArrayList.get(i).getElements().get(j).getDistance() != null) {
                                            distance = distance + rowArrayList.get(i).getElements().get(j).getDistance().getValue();

                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                                Log.e("source..lat", "" + mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                                Log.e("source..log", "" + mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                                Log.e("destination..lat", "" + location.getLatitude());
                                Log.e("destination..log", "" + location.getLongitude());
                                Log.e("distance:", "" + distance / 1000);

                                final double dist = distance / 1000;

                                //call service to send location

                                srclat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                                srclog = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                                destlat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                                destlog = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                                total = dist;

                                Travel travel = new Travel();
                                travel.setId(id);
                                travel.setTid(t_id);
                                travel.setSrcLat(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
                                travel.setSrcLog(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                                travel.setDestLat(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                                travel.setDestLog(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                                travel.setDist(String.valueOf(dist));

                                // check for accuracy of location
                                Log.e("meter", String.valueOf(distance));
                                double speed = distance / (location.getTime() - mLastLocation.getTime());

                                if (isBetterLocation(location, mLastLocation) && speed > 3 && distance < 300) {
                                    if (mLastLocation.getLatitude() != 0 && mLastLocation.getLongitude() != 0 && location.getLatitude() != 0 && location.getLongitude() != 0) {

                                        if (mLastLocation.getLatitude() != location.getLatitude() && mLastLocation.getLongitude() != location.getLongitude()) {
                                            makeMyTrip.makeTrip(id, t_id, String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()),
                                                    String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()), String.valueOf(dist)).enqueue(new Callback<MyRes>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onResponse(Call<MyRes> call, Response<MyRes> response) {


                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(Call<MyRes> call, Throwable t) {

                                                }
                                            });


                                        }


                                    }
                                }

                                mLastLocation.set(location);
                            }


                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MapData> call, Throwable t) {
                        mLastLocation.set(location);
                    }
                });

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How do you measure the distance between locations ?

Comment: from the google distance matrix api..

Answer (score 1):

You have to take step by step distance between two lat lon means previous lat lon and new lat lon using this formula. And at the add all that distance give you accurate distance. If you need more accuracy add time and speed factor as well.

```
 public static float getDistanceInMiles(double currentLatitude, double currentLongitude, double newLatitude, double newLongitude) {
    double latitude = newLatitude;
    double longitude = newLongitude;
    float distance = 0;
    Location crntLocation = new Location("crntlocation");
    crntLocation.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
    crntLocation.setLongitude(currentLongitude);
    Location newLocation = new Location("newlocation");
    newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
    distance = crntLocation.distanceTo(newLocation);
    //distance =crntLocation.distanceTo(newLocation) / 1000; // in km
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: I have already calculate step by step distance from previous lat lon and new  lat lon but the location co ordinate gets many times wrong and result distance between them gives wrong.So how i filtered wrong coordinate of location.I have also use function for filtering from google documentation.But not work perfectly..

Comment: You have to add time and speed factor for accurate result

Comment: take time when when you get previous and new lat lon and calculate speed using s=d/t and compare that speed with vehicle speed eg if speed of vehicle is 70 km/hour calculate speed and if speed is more then vehicle speed ignore that point.

Comment: I am using this approach it give accurate result with accurate billing

Comment: How do i calculate vehicle speed from device.while travelling.?

Comment: using formula speed=distance/time and assume speed of vehicle eg bike travel with speed of 70km/hr.  distance =distance between two lat lon and time is time difference between two lat lon.this gve you speed in KM/hr and compare this speed with vhicle speed if greater ignore that speed and lat lon.